# Android: ListView has strange margins

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to make an app with an action bar, floating button and `ListView`.

When I add the `ListView` in Android Studio it has always big margins to all sides.

Whatever I change in the layout code it doesn't help it always looks like this:
[image]

My layout code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="appenzeller.de.glimpse.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainList" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_bar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_addc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"
            android:onClick="addNewEntry"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the whole file with root view item. I would assume that it has the default passing/margin. And the listviews width is set to "wrap_content" you probably want "match_parent".

Comment: updated it - was missing before sorry

Comment: Just remove **padding lines from your Root Layout**. i.e. Remove `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"` and all others..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

from your RelativeLayout. You said "all sides", I can only see left/right. But if it's all sides you also have to remove "paddingTop" and "paddingBottom".

Comment: The top margins where only visible when scrolling. Removing those lines helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your relative layout is using padding which means you are leaving some space from sides.

Removing the following lines will remove padding

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

if you want to remove padding from top and bottom as well you can remove following tag as well

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```